# NameSpace for ICallHandler in 4.6.1 framework?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

Please do let me know the  `NameSpace` for   ICallHandler in **4.6.1** framework??

Earlier it was in `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension`

I am using unity 4.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.interceptionextension.icallhandler.aspx), ICallHandler has been deprecated, and you need to consider moving to something else.

I do know that Prism has moved to NuGet, you can find it here: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Core/

And Unity was separated into it's own "thing":

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/

But I do not know for sure ifyou'll find ICallHandler in there.

Comment: Oops Gone case then...its being using in one of our old projects now I have to migrate the same in 2015 :(

Comment: Yup - such is the life of a developer :) Please mark the question as answered if I managed to answer your question :)

Comment: Any suggestion please how to move further??

Comment: That's hard to answer without knowing where you are now. If you need to preserve compatibility with Unity, I'd have a look at the new NuGet package. Otherwise, I would consider a different IoC container. My favourite is StructureMap, but whatever you choose, be sure to pick something that has a solid team working on updates.

Comment: New Dll is there Unity.Interception in Nuget